# Why the difference in color when a question has an answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta, design

Why is there a difference in color for the accepted answers between Meta and Meta Questions?

In the image below, the first section is what you see when you click on the Questions tab when on Meta.  The second section is what you see when you switch from SE to Meta by clicking the "Meta" link in the header.  Shouldn't these colors be the same?

[image]

Comment: +1, Yes there is a difference, in CSS its `#E1E818` and `#fbfabd`

Comment: @Habib I can see it, but it is very slight.  I wouldn't have even noticed it if it wasn't for this question

Comment: @psubsee2003, yes I had to open in different window side by side to see the difference and then inspect the css.

Comment: Now the "status-completed" etc. tags on the right hand side and on the actual questions look like different colors to me and they're not. I hope you're happy.

Comment: I'm always happy, brotha.  :o)